# c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea) error in raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

hi i want to work with opencv in raspberry pi

but i have a error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testface.py", line 76, in

```
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /home/pi/opencv-4.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:272: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'

please see my code:

```html
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# initialize GPIO
redLed = 21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(redLed, GPIO.OUT)

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--picamera", type=int, default=-1,
 help="whether or not the Raspberry Pi camera should be used")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warmup
print("[INFO] waiting for camera to warmup...")
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=args["picamera"] > 0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

# define the lower and upper boundaries of the object
# to be detected in the HSV color space
colorLower = (24, 100, 100) 
colorUpper = (44, 255, 255) 

# Start with LED off
print("\n Starting..... ==> Press 'q' to quit Program \n")
GPIO.output(redLed, GPIO.LOW)
ledOn = False

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
 # grab the next frame from the video stream, Invert 180o, resize the
 # frame, and convert it to the HSV color space
 frame = vs.read()
 frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
 frame = imutils.rotate(frame, angle=180)
 hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

 # construct a mask for the obect color, then perform
 # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
 # blobs left in the mask
 mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, colorLower, colorUpper)
 mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
 mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

 # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
 # (x, y) center of the object
 cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
 center = None
 #print("hey")

 if cnts is None:
  cnts = [0]

 # only proceed if at least one contour was found
 if len(cnts) > 0:
  # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
  # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
  # centroid
  c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
  ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
  M = cv2.moments(c)
  center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

  # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
  if radius > 10:
   # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
   # then update the list of tracked points
   cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
    (0, 255, 255), 2)
   cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

   # if the led is not already on, turn the LED on
   if not ledOn:
    GPIO.output(redLed, GPIO.HIGH)
    ledOn = True
    print("fined")

 # if the object is not detected, turn the LED off
 elif ledOn:
  GPIO.output(redLed, GPIO.LOW)
  ledOn = False

 # show the frame to our screen
 cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
 key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

 # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
 if key == ord("q"):
  break

# do a bit of cleanup
print("\n Exiting Program and cleanup stuff \n")
GPIO.cleanup()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

look here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/102465/error-calling-contourarea/

and maybe you need to replace:

```
cnts = [0]
```

with:

```
cnts = []
```

so you will get:

```
if cnts == None:
    cnts = []
```

your code will be:

```html
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# initialize GPIO
redLed = 21
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(redLed, GPIO.OUT)

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--picamera", type=int, default=-1,
 help="whether or not the Raspberry Pi camera should be used")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warmup
print("[INFO] waiting for camera to warmup...")
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=args["picamera"] > 0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

# define the lower and upper boundaries of the object
# to be detected in the HSV color space
colorLower = (24, 100, 100) 
colorUpper = (44, 255, 255) 

# Start with LED off
print("\n Starting..... ==> Press 'q' to quit Program \n")
GPIO.output(redLed, GPIO.LOW)
ledOn = False

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
 # grab the next frame from the video stream, Invert 180o, resize the
 # frame, and convert it to the HSV color space
 frame = vs.read()
 frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
 frame = imutils.rotate(frame, angle=180)
 hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

 # construct a mask for the obect color, then perform
 # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
 # blobs left in the mask
 mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, colorLower, colorUpper)
 mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
 mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

 # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
 # (x, y) center of the object
 cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
 center = None
 #print("hey")

 if cnts is None:
  cnts = []

 # only proceed if at least one contour was found
 if len(cnts) > 0:
  # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
  # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
  # centroid
  c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
  ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
  M = cv2.moments(c)
  center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

  # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
  if radius > 10:
   # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
   # then update the list of tracked points
   cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
    (0, 255, 255), 2)
   cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

   # if the led is not already on, turn the LED on
   if not ledOn:
    GPIO.output(redLed, GPIO.HIGH)
    ledOn = True
    print("fined")

 # if the object is not detected, turn the LED off
 elif ledOn:
  GPIO.output(redLed, GPIO.LOW)
  ledOn = False

 # show the frame to our screen
 cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
 key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

 # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
 if key == ord("q"):
  break

# do a bit of cleanup
print("\n Exiting Program and cleanup stuff \n")
GPIO.cleanup()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

that will work i think

Comment: becuse you will need the list but you give them a "empty" list(only a 0 in it)

Comment: hi
i replace : 

cnts = [0]

with 

cnts = []  . but get same error

Comment: when cnts get 1 and run 
if len(cnts) > 0:
i get same error:

c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /home/pi/opencv-4.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:272: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
```

to

```
cnts = cnts[1] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[0]
```

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57981226)