# How to calculate blob convexity in Java with OpenCV: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)) in contourArea

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm using the SimpleBlobDetector C++ OpenCV code as an example for finding blobs.
Since I want to know the value of each search criteria of the blob (for development analysis) I can't just use the SimpleBlobDetector.
I'm working on Android so need to convert to Java.

To calculate the convexity, SimpleBlobDetector uses a thing called Hull. The C++ implementation:

```
        std::vector < Point > hull;
        convexHull(contours[contourIdx], hull);
        double area = moms.m00;
        double hullArea = contourArea(hull);
        // and so on
```

I cannot say I know exactly what this code does, but I want to re-implement ... in Java. I wrote:

```
MatOfInt hull = new MatOfInt();
Imgproc.convexHull(contour, hull);
assert(hull.depth() == CvType.CV_32S);
assert(hull.channels() == 1);
// >>>> NOTE: crashes on next line :(
double hullArea = Imgproc.contourArea(hull);
```

Note that I used MatOfInt for hull since that is what convexHull requires. Java cannot directly use std::vector since it's a C++ generic.

Thing is, my code crashes and this is logged (in logcat):

> OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0 && (depth ==
> CV_32F || depth == CV_32S)) in contourArea, file
> /home/ci/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp, line 315

which comes from this line in contourArea() C++:

```
int npoints = contour.checkVector(2);
int depth = contour.depth();
CV_Assert(npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S));
```

I added asserts to verify that the depth is CV_32S so that's not it.
checkVector(2) requires 2 channels, but mine has only 1. That's why it crashes.

Is the check wrong (bug in OpenCV)? Or do I really need a 2-channel Mat? How to I get such a Mat?

I do all the normal stuff to get a contour: convert Mat to grayscale, threshold() and then findContours(). Could include it, but it's alot, it's not structured for here and I don't think it's helpful for this question. But I'll include if you ask.

So, how to successfully call contourArea() in this case?

Is there a different way to calculate convexity?

---

@ChristophRackwitz [Having the Following Error Message: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::contourArea'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980005/having-the-following-error-message-error-215assertion-failed-npoints-0) is about the same (at least similar) assertion failure in the C++ code. But definitely a different issue/cause. That issue is about indexing to the right return value from a Python call. findContours() is void in the Java binding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having the Following Error Message: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV\_32F || depth == CV\_32S) in function 'cv::contourArea'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980005/having-the-following-error-message-error-215assertion-failed-npoints-0)

Comment: the assertion is proper. checkVector(2) required. it must be either an Nx2 1ch matrix or an Nx1 2ch matrix.

Comment: The documentation says this about the `hull` argument of `convexHull`: "It is either an integer vector of indices or vector of points. In the first case, the hull elements are 0-based indices of the convex hull points in the original array (since the set of convex hull points is a subset of the original point set). In the second case, hull elements are the convex hull points themselves." Since you get single channel output, I guess it's the former, not the latter. Look at example [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html) how they handle that.

Comment: `returnPoints` is true by default, so you should have gotten points. it *is* sensitive to the `hull` argument's type. `MatOfInt` may be the issue. or maybe it's an issue with the java bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @DanMasek brought me to an answer. I looked at the C++ implementation for convexHull() to see how the output param could be two different types. The C++ function accepts parameter "bool returnPoints" which selects to output Points vs. indexes. The Java binding does not have this parameter and I can't find the Java binding code, but Dan is surely right: since Java's convexHull output param is MatOfInt, it must be returning indexes. With some research, I discovered that the indexes are into the contour's array of Point. So, I create a MatOfPoint (same as contour) to pass to contourArea.

```
private double getHullArea() {
    MatOfInt hullIndexMat = new MatOfInt();
    Imgproc.convexHull(contour, hullIndexMat);

    // convert hull indexes to points
    Point[] contourPoints = contour.toArray();
    List<Integer> hullIndices = hullIndexMat.toList();
    Point[] hullPoints = new Point[hullIndices.size()];
    for (int h = 0; h < hullIndices.size(); ++h) {
        hullPoints[h] = contourPoints[hullIndices.get(h)];
    }
    var hullMat = new MatOfPoint(hullPoints);

    return Imgproc.contourArea(hullMat);
}
```